# Type of container

Tags: image-identification

What do we call the big round thing in the image that contains the small bowls?

Is this a:

> a. container
> b. bowl
> c. dish
> d. plate
> e. platter
> f. OR WHAT?

[image: picture of a dish holding several small bowls of food arranged around some rice]

Answer (score 1):

In Britain, where we have a lot of Indian restaurants, we are used to calling the main dish a **thali**, or **thali plate**, and a main dish with a set of smaller bowls or dishes is a **thali set**. Pronounced like 'tally'.

> Thali Plate
>
> A thali is a round platter with an eared rim. ... The thali is
> generally made with steel or copper. Other dishes served on a thali
> include vegetables, yogurt, chutney, and pickles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a 'serving dish'. To be more specific, I'd call it a 'divided serving dish' or a 'serving dish with compartments'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want to Anglicise, which depends in turn on who you are talking to.

It is a **thali**, for example, being [sold on ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FULL-STAINLESS-STEEL-THALI-DINNER-SET-28-5cm/133197026414).  This is the most specific, but many English speakers won't know this [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thali) word.

It is a "stainless steel, Indian style serving tray".

It is a dish, a plate, a tray,  a platter. You could use any of these words, and combine with adjectives if you need to describe it to someone who is not familiar with Indian food service.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given the correct name of **thali**, but I wanted to add what I thought before learning that word here:

- *container* implies full enclosure for storage or shipment
- *bowl* has a curved bottom, either partially or completely
- *dish* is a generic term and best avoided when there’s a more specific one
- *plate* is flat with no lip
- *platter* has several food items directly on it, usually with no divisions

One you didn’t list:

- *tray* is a dish for carrying other dishes, but not food directly

Your picture appears to be a combination of a tray (carrying toppings and sauce) and a platter (carrying rice and bread), so someone who doesn’t know the word *thali* would likely use one of those two words, or just the generic dish rather than using a more specific word they knew wasn’t right.